# how to align web view activity indicator center in titanium sdk - iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mobile, sdk, webview, titanium

I'm having a web view added to a  window. On opening the window it shows the activity indicator while loading the web url at vertically center and horizontally left to the view.

On changing the orientation of device, it activity indicator moves to center of the view.

how to make to display the activity indicator in center on opening the window.
is their any method to reload/refresh the window or web view?

Problem is with iPhone device.
[image]

Comment: post your code(which you used to create WebView)

Comment: var termswebView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
   url : "http://google.com/",
 });

Answer (score 1):

create webview without using top, bottom, left, right then activity indicator positioned at center

```
var extwebview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: hostUrl
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: if not specified top, bottom, left or right then the activity indicator will be on left top corner, I'm using titanium sdk version 2.1

Comment: create a parent view with positions(left,top,bottom,right), then add webview to parent view... refer this gist https://gist.github.com/6b8c5ce115477abc03a6

Comment: @Udhaya are you from chennai?

Comment: @Udhaya if my answer helps you mark it as correct, it may helps some one who having similar issue